# "make" command permission denied

Tags: python, django, makefile, gnu-make

I have a Django application which has a custom folder I named `codefiles`. Inside it, are many subfolders with random names. Further, inside each of those folder, is a Makefile. I'm currently confused why it says `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` when I call the following code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["make", "-f", os.path.join(directory, "Makefile")], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True, shell=True)
```

What might be the problem here?

EDIT:
Even calling the following code below causes a Permission denied error:

```
current_directory = os.getcwd()
logging.debug("current_dir: " + str(current_directory));
```

EDIT2: This is getting weirder and weirder. Even a comment results a Permission denied error. Here is the error log:

```
File "./src/tasks/views.py", line 1178, in test_run_code
# create the make file
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: change folder permissions?

Comment: @DiegoContreras I already did. All the permissions are already 0777

Comment: Did you do any weird moves installing python or packages? Did you hack any python core files? I only see a folder permission problem, maybe make sure the 0777 is applied to all the folders/files involved? Maybe use `chmod` recursively with -R

Comment: Since you have set `shell=True`, Python will attempt to invoke a shell here and pass the content to it.  So, the problem has to be with your shell somehow, not with the commands you're passing to the shell.  This error means the shell can't be started.  FWIW, you really do NOT want to set `shell=True` for security (and simplicity) reasons, unless you absolutely need it (such as you want to write a shell script, or you're running on Windows).

Comment: I don't know why, but when I restarted the server (I'm using Google Cloud Compute), it's already fixed. Do you have any idea why that happened? Is there such thing as 'server cache'?

Comment: Well, you'd have to define what you mean by "server cache".  If it's working now I doubt there's any way to figure out what the actual problem was.  Certainly, not without a much longer and more in-depth debugging session that anyone is likely to want to undertake through the comments of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: What is your operating system? Have you enabled SELinux or AppArmor?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I'm using Ubuntu and I believe I haven't enabled any of those